# Change email username in email sent by Sendgrid

Tags: email, sendgrid, strapi

I created a sendgrid plugin inside strapi enviorment.

I need to change the defaukt email sending user name into another one

eg: defaultEmail : test123@gmail.com

Once the sendgrid send the email to user it should receive the username as
**Team Test**

But it receiving **test123**.

I changes the username from gmail setting also but it did not change

Answer (score 1):

To set the from name of an email sent from SendGrid you need to [pass the name and email address to the API as an object](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send).

For example:

```js
const sg = require("@sendgrid/mail");

const message = {
  from: {
    email: "test123@gmail.com",
    name: "Team Test"
  },
  ...otherEmailOptions
};

sg.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
sg.send(message);
```

Note that your Gmail settings will not affect any emails you send using SendGrid. When you send an email through SendGrid, it is sent independently of any other service or servers on which you can send email with that address.